# Calculate time difference within Pandas while adding a new column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time

I have a dataframe that contains start and end times. I would like to calculate the time difference in seconds of each row, whilst adding a new column for this new calculation.

```
     dataframe = df


    starttime                  endtime                     ID

    1/7/2020 2:32:15 PM        1/7/2020 2:32:16 PM          A
    1/8/2020 2:33:20 PM        1/8/2020 2:33:22 PM          B
```

I would like this outcome:

```
    starttime                  endtime                      ID      Diff

    1/7/2020 2:32:15 PM        1/7/2020 2:32:16 PM          A       1 sec
    1/8/2020 2:33:20 PM        1/8/2020 2:33:22 PM          B       2 sec
```

Currently I have this command:

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import datetime
    from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
    from datetime import date


     df['Diff'] = df['endtime'] - df['starttime']
     df['Diff']=df['Diff']/np.timedelta64(1,'s')

     print(df)
```

Comment: I was not able to produce the time difference in seconds

Comment: What happened instead?

Comment: I kept getting a Type Error. The code that was provided solves the dilemma I had

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as below. You will get the difference in seconds (you will not get the text 'sec' though)

```
df['Diff'] = (pd.to_datetime(df.endtime) - pd.to_datetime(df.starttime)).dt.total_seconds()
```

**Output**

```
            starttime   endtime            ID   Diff
0   1/7/2020 14:32:15   1/7/2020 14:32:16   A   1.0
1   1/8/2020 14:33:20   1/8/2020 14:33:22   B   2.0
```

Comment: ok so I am adding your command after this:                df['Diff'] = df['endtime'] - df['starttime']
     df['Diff']=df['Diff']/np.timedelta64(1,'s')

Comment: You don't need any of the earlier lines. You can use the code i have put directly.

Comment: I will try now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

there you go

```
df['mydiff'] = pd.to_datetime(df.starttime) - pd.to_datetime(df.endtime)
```

Comment: Isn’t that going to create a column of `timedelta` objects? Not time difference in seconds? Or am I misunderstanding?